# Android How to `getFilesDir` in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How can I implement the `getFilesDir` command in a broadcast receiver? If i can't use that, what similar function can I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I implement the getFilesDir command in a broadcast receiver?

If by "implement" you mean "call", you can call `getFilesDir()` on the `Context` passed to your `onReceive()` method.

Comment: yes i mean call; can you please show me what you mean>

Comment: i got it; figured it out